# Computing enthalpy of formation of dissolved gas from its enthalpy of dissolution

Tags: thermodynamics, aqueous-solution, enthalpy

Provided that I know the enthalpy of formation $\Delta H_f^0(X_{g})$ of a substance $X$ in gas phase and its [enthalpy of dissolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_change_of_solution) $\Delta H^0_{sol}(X)$ in the same conditions, considering that the dissolution reaction is $X_g \leftrightharpoons X_{aq}$
 is it legit to consider that the enthalpy of formation of that substance $X$ in aqueous phase would be $\Delta H^0_f(X_{aq}) = \Delta H^0_{sol}(X) - \Delta H_f^0(X_{g})$?

As a concrete exemple, considering that the enthalpy of formation of $H_2$ in gas phase is 0 kJ/mol and that its enthalpy of dissolution is approximately -4.15 kJ/mol (using the data provided [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry%27s_law#Temperature_dependence)), can we conclude that the enthalpy of formation of $H_2$ in aqueous phase is approximately -4.15 kJ/mol?

Comment: That seems correct.